# How to get short day name in Postgres, e.g. "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"

Tags: postgresql

How can you select short day name in Postgres, e.g. "Mon", "Tue", "Wed"?

*Not* the full day name "Monday", "Tuesday", "Wednesday".

Answer (score 19):

`to_char(NOW(), 'Dy')` or `'dy'` or `'DY'`

for 'Fri', 'fri', or 'FRI', respectively.

Reference: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-formatting.html#FUNCTIONS-FORMATTING-DATETIME-TABLE

Comment: Works awesome. `SELECT TO_CHAR(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'Dy')` Short sweet and to the point.Thanks for the help